# Bitbucket pipeline fails with ssh error: ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory Host key verification failed

Tags: ssh, bitbucket, ssh-keys, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to ssh into my EC2 server from bitbucket pipelines and get the below error.

```
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Host key verification failed.
```

What does this mean and how can I fix this?

Note that I have already configured SSH keys for this repository and the existing servers are working properly. This happens in a newly-created server and I'm afraid whether I have missed any configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short Answer

**Since it is a new server, you have to fetch the server details on the Bitbucket side** by following the below steps.

- Go to `Repository Settings` > `Pipelines` section > `SSH Keys` > `Known Hosts` section > Input public IP of server > Click Fetch > Click Add Host

## Long Answer

The error message `ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory Host key verification failed.` indicates that there was an error while trying to establish an SSH connection to a remote server.

The first part of the error message, `ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory`, suggests that the SSH client is unable to find the `ssh-askpass` program in the expected location. `ssh-askpass` is a program used by the SSH client to prompt the user for a passphrase or password when needed.

- If SSH keys are properly configured, there's no need to prompt for passphrase from user input, hence ideally, `ssh-askpass` should not get called in this situation. **It is likely that the problem is in SSH key setup.**

The second part of the error message, `Host key verification failed` indicates that the SSH client was not able to verify the authenticity of the remote server's host key. This could happen if the remote server's key has changed since the last time you connected to it, or if the key is being intercepted or spoofed by a man-in-the-middle attack.

- In this situation, since the SSH command could not verify the authenticity of the remote server either by SSH keys or manually requesting a password, it shows a `Host key verification failed` error.

To fix this, first, make sure the remote server has no issues in terms of communicating with Bitbucket. If any of these has errors, then they should be separately addressed.

```
# Add id_rsa to ssh agent
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
ssh-add -l

# Remove existing bitbucket.org host record from known_hosts file
ssh-keygen -R bitbucket.org

# Re-add bitbucket.org host record to known_hosts file
ssh-keyscan -t rsa bitbucket.org >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

# Authenticate to bitbucket via ssh key
ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
```

If all these are working, then the server is good and the issue should be on the Bitbucket side.

And as per the details provided, **since it is a new server, you have to fetch the server details on the Bitbucket side** by following the below steps. This must be the missing configuration.

- Go to `Repository Settings` > `Pipelines` section > `SSH Keys` > `Known Hosts` section > Input public IP of server > Click Fetch > Click Add Host